# Whole House Filter Cartridge Centering Device

Tags: plumbing, water, filter

I have a whole house water filter, which takes 2.5" x 10" cartridge filters string/carbon.  Sometimes it is difficult to line up the cartridge in the housing with the water input when the filter is a bit off center.  I was wondering if they make a piece of plastic or metal that would be placed on the filter so that it centers the filter in the housing.

I would think it would have to be wagon wheel shaped or have holes in it, so water could pass through it.

Does such a product/device exist?  I would imagine that someone could 3D print this type of device, but I wouldn't know where to begin with that.

The water filter I have is something like this: [A.O. Smith Filter](https://www.lowes.com/pd/A-O-Smith-AO-WH-PREV-Single-Stage-4-GPM-Mechanical-Filtration-Whole-House-Water-Filtration-System/1000576411)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anywhere near enough need for such a thing. I'm going to guess following the wrong order of installation to have that problem.

Place the filter on the input first, then put the housing on. I think you're doing the opposite, to have the problem you  describe.

Comment: I tried putting the filter on first, it simply slips off the input.  There doesn't see to be enough friction to keep the filter on the pipe.  I tried putting a PVC coupling and a short piece of pipe, but then there is not enough room between the filter and the input, so I can't screw on the filter housing.

Comment: I wonder if I could put some tape around the input pipe to create friction so that the filter will not slide off.  I will try this next time in addition to the suggestion about filling the cartridge housing with water.

Answer (score 1):

It is frustrating when you find out after it's all tightened and you turn on the water and there is a leak.

When I got my first on in 1994, I was told that the process is supposed to be that you fill the housing **1/3 to 2/3 full of water** before screwing it up.  This helps hold the filter cartridge in place while you turn the housing.

Comment: I forgot to try this technique when I changed the filter.  I'll try this technique next time, stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

If the filter does not stay in place when inserted, you are trying to keep it aligned while using the filter housing to lift it up. That process will not allow filter to stay straight and fit in the insert.

Possible solution is to make the filter stay aligned is to use extension insert (pvc pipe) that fits inside the filter and inside the housing opening.

Comment: I tried making an extension insert via a pvc coupling and short piece of pipe, made the space between the filter and the input housing too long/wide so that I could no longer screw the filter housing on the filter base.  I also tried cutting the coupling in half, but then there wasn't enough area on the coupling to hold the input pipe and cut off pipe.